# HTML5 Audio player stops after playing one minute

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Hi I used HTML5 audio player and linked a mp3 file and autoplay functionality did . But it's time duration 37 minutes but it stop after 1 minute.

Here is my code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/gabtmwxv/)

```js
var audio1 = document.getElementById("player1");
var btn1 = document.getElementById("pButton1");
var pause_hover1 = document.getElementById("pause-hover");
var vid = document.getElementById("player1");
        
btn1.addEventListener("click", function(){
 if (audio1.paused) {
   audio1.play();
       
  btn1.classList.remove("pause1");
  btn1.classList.add("play1");
  pause_hover1.style.display = "none";

 } else  {
   audio1.pause();
           
  btn1.classList.remove("play1");
  btn1.classList.add("pause1");
   pause_hover1.style.display = "block";
 }
});
```

```html
<audio loop id="player1" autoplay="true" src="http://downloadmotivations.com/wp-content/themes/downloadmotivation/Dream.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        
</audio>
<div id="audioplayer1">
 <button id="pButton1" style="background: transparent;" class="play1"> audio</button>
      
</div>
```

Comment: well actually I have been listing to this audio for 3mins and it's still playing !

Comment: @Majid it's playing because I applied loop there. It starting loop again after 1 minute from beginning. u can try it through url also http://downloadmotivations.com/wp-content/themes/downloadmotivation/Dream%20-%20Motivational%20Audio%20Compilation.mp3

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your code to the following and it's working now at least at my end.

if you don't want control please remove `controls` from `audio tag`

```js
var audio1 = document.getElementById("player1");
var btn1 = document.getElementById("pButton1");
var pause_hover1 = document.getElementById("pause-hover");
var vid = document.getElementById("player1");
        
btn1.addEventListener("click", function(){
 if (audio1.paused) {
   audio1.play();
       
  btn1.classList.remove("pause1");
  btn1.classList.add("play1");
  pause_hover1.style.display = "none";

 } else  {
   audio1.pause();
           
  btn1.classList.remove("play1");
  btn1.classList.add("pause1");
   pause_hover1.style.display = "block";
 }
});
```

```html
<audio autoplay="true" controls id="player1">
  <source src="http://downloadmotivations.com/wp-content/themes/downloadmotivation/Dream.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="http://downloadmotivations.com/wp-content/themes/downloadmotivation/Dream.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<div id="audioplayer1">
 <button id="pButton1" style="background: transparent;" class="play1"> audio</button>
      
</div>
```

Comment: ok I am using google chrome browser and just checked ur snippet it also stopped after 1:10 minutes. Here is my screencapture video check this http://screencast.com/t/4Gd0T2rwkt0f. it's not working.

Comment: well,I left it to play it's already played for 4.21 and still running. you may check file itself directly and also check with other browsers and different maybe device or PC.

Comment: Moreover,I suggest renaming your mp3 file name properly with - or _ and no space Dream - Motivational Audio Compilation.mp3 and preferably all lowercase

Comment: thanks it was for naming space in file location my code was ok.